# Laravel Form with Validation and store Jquery add html elements

Tags: jquery, laravel, validation

i use Laravel and i have a form with laravel validation and required fields (so when I get errors, it reload always all page, and I keep values with old blade tag).
All good, but I did a button to add some text boxes with jquery

```
$(".add-more").click(function(){ 
      var html = $(".copy").html();
      $(".after-add-more").before(html);
    });

    $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
      $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
    });
```

How can i save old values and the created n-html elements when Laravel reload all page at every invalid message after submission ?
Thx

Comment: Your question is not clear try adding some code so that we can understand.

Comment: Best practice would be to not reload the page and keep the html as is. Manage the validations without reload.

Comment: Also in Laravel framework? I know that Laravel always reload, for this exists old value retriever.....are u sure?

Comment: Well I would suggest to use `localStorage` save data into `localstorage`, retrieve when you need it, but remember to empty `localstorage` on each reload page.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple, you dont reload the whole page, include an element with laravel's @include for example, the contents of the table are in another blade file, but it is included

```
<table class="table tablesorter ">
    <thead class=" text-primary">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">TIPO</th>
            <th scope="col">fecha</th>
            <th scope="col">Monto</th>
            <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table">
        @include('component-table')
    </tbody>
</table>
```

component-table.blade.php

```
    <tr>
        <td>hi</td>
        <td>
            test
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="text-right">

        </td>
    </tr>
```

Now, you can make a controller that returns this view and reload only the table when you call that controller and just replace the html with jquery's html() function

```
//on controller 
    public function table()
    {
        return view('component-table.blade.php');
    }
//js
    async function reloadTable(){
        await $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "{{ route('component-table') }}",
            data: '',
            success: function(response){
                            $('#table').html(response)
                        }
        });
    }
```

Comment: if i reload only for example the table part, laravel validation doesn't work for part that no reloaded, i think i need to work with old values lavaravel capabilities or not?Thx

Comment: Whatever needs validation you can separate into another component, i usually separate everything by components, Forms, Tables, Modals, etc etc, so that everything can be manipulated without affecting the other, if you need a form validated and dont want the rest of the page reloaded, just put that form in another blade template and include it, flashing the input or errors into the session

Comment: I mean the child blade must be fixed and father reloaded

Answer (score 0):

At least working with blade i obtained this, i dunno if is correct.
Resume what i have. A form with several fields and one button that add other 2 html field each times u press this(one is a combobox, with name='tipo' that take values from a table (called moyens) in the db)

```
@if( old('tipo') )
   @foreach (old('tipo') as $key => $value) 
    <!--<div>{{ $key . ' => ' . $value }}</div>-->
    <div class="col-sm-5">
    <select class="form-control" name="tipo[]">
        @foreach($moyens as $moyen)
            <option value="{{$moyen->code}}" @if($moyen->code == '$value') 'selected' @endif>{{ $moyen->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">&#8364</span>
            <input type="number" min="0" step="0.01" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="100" class="form-control" name="importo[]" placeholder="importo" value="{{old('polizza')}}">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Cancella</button>
    </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

All works, but I CANNOT retrieve the old selected values in the combobox/es

Is this part

```
 <option value="{{$moyen->code}}" @if($moyen->code == '$value') 'selected' @endif>{{ $moyen->name }}</option>
```

Can be correct this approch?
Thx